# Generating KML files with Ruby

Tags: ruby, kml, geo

I'm using the [ruby_kml](https://github.com/schleyfox/ruby_kml) gem right now to try to generate KML from some data in my model.
I also tried [georuby](https://github.com/nofxx/georuby).

Both of them, when they generate XML it seems to be coming back escaped like this:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<kml xmlns=\"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1\">\n  <Folder>\n    <name>San Francisco</name>\n    <LineStyle>\n      <color>#0D7215</color>\n    </LineStyle>\n    <Placemark>\n      <name>21 Google Bus</name>\n      <description>\n        <![CDATA[Click to add description.]]>\n      </description>\n      <LineString>\n        <coordinates>37.784282779035216,-122.42228507995605 37.784144999999995,-122.42225699999999,37.784084,-122.42274499999999,37.785472,-122.423023,37.785391,-122.423564,37.785364,-122.423839,37.785418,-122.424714,37.785410999999996,-122.42497999999999,37.785391,-122.42522,37.784839,-122.42956,37.784631,-122.431297,37.782576,-122.43086799999999,37.776969,-122.42975399999999,37.776759999999996,-122.431384,37.776368,-122.431305 37.776368,-122.431305,37.777699999999996,-122.431575,37.778746999999996,-122.42335399999999,37.773609,-122.42231199999999,37.773013999999996,-122.42222799999999,37.772974999999995,-122.42222799999999,37.772915,-122.42226799999999,37.772774,-122.422446,37.772636999999996,-122.422585,37.772562,-122.42263399999999,37.772521999999995,-122.422643,37.771588,-122.42253799999999,37.771631,-122.421759</coordinates>\n      </LineString>\n    </Placemark>\n    <LineStyle>\n      <color>#0071CA</color>\n    </LineStyle>\n    <Placemark>\n      <name>45 Inverter</name>\n      <description>\n        <![CDATA[Click to add description.]]>\n      </description>\n      <LineString>\n        <coordinates>37.792490234462946,-122.40863800048828 37.792516,-122.408429,37.793068,-122.408541,37.792957,-122.409357,37.792051,-122.409189,37.788289999999996,-122.40841499999999,37.785495,-122.407866,37.785713,-122.406229,37.785713,-122.40591599999999,37.785699,-122.40576999999999,37.785658,-122.40568999999999,37.783249999999995,-122.40270699999999,37.778850999999996,-122.40827499999999,37.779104,-122.408577</coordinates>\n      </LineString>\n    </Placemark>\n    <LineStyle>\n      <color>#AD0101</color>\n    </LineStyle>\n    <Placemark>\n      <name>82 X Wing</name>\n      <description>\n        <![CDATA[Click to add description.]]>\n      </description>\n      <LineString>\n        <coordinates></coordinates>\n      </LineString>\n    </Placemark>\n    <LineStyle>\n      <color>#AD0101</color>\n    </LineStyle>\n    <Placemark>\n      <name>93 X Wing</name>\n      <description>\n        <![CDATA[Click to add description.]]>\n      </description>\n      <LineString>\n        <coordinates></coordinates>\n      </LineString>\n    </Placemark>\n  </Folder>\n</kml>\n"
```

I'm not sure why it should be coming it escaped, since it definitely is not valid XML.

georuby does the same.

Does anyone know why it's coming out escaped and also how to unescape it?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
map = self;
kml = KMLFile.new
folder = KML::Folder.new(:name => map[:name])
map.lines.each do |line|
  folder.features << KML::LineStyle.new(
    color: line.color,
  )
  folder.features << KML::Placemark.new(
    :name => line.name,
    :geometry => KML::LineString.new(:coordinates => line.coordinates),
    :description => line.description
  )
end
kml.objects << folder
kml.render
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: How do you know the data looks like that? Are you printing, or inspecting, the values? Typically escaped double-quotes means you're displaying an inspected string, and what you're seeing is technically correct, since those are embedded insides the delimiting double-quotes. And, at that point there's no need to remove the escaping.

Comment: so I tried to do `puts line.name` and I get back strings without quotes.  Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by inspected string :(